# What did Masatoshi Nei 1972 mean by "However, evolution does not occur so as to assure this property at least at the nucleotide level."?

Tags: evolution, theoretical-biology

In [Nei 1972](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/282771) he describes what is now called [Nei's standard genetic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_distance#Nei%27s_standard_genetic_distance). This [math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382501/does-neis-standard-genetic-distance-obey-identity-of-indiscernibles) provides an exerpt to the definition of Nei's standard genetic distance. In this paper he states

> In the present measure of genetic distance, the triangle inequality, which is often assumed in numerical taxonomy (see, e.g., Levandowsky and Winter 1971), does not hold. However, evolution does not occur so as to assure this property at least at the nucleotide level.

The triangle inequality can be nice to have, but it is fine that functions do not always have it. But I find his justification for not having it to be perplexing.

What did Nei mean that "evolution does not occur so as to assure this property at least at the nucleotide level"? And in what sense did use this criterion to decide that the other properties of his function *were* assured by evolution at a nucleotide level?

Comment: I don't have access to the paper so it's hard to place the quote in context. A little more surrounding text might help. But at a guess he might mean that the distance between individuals or populations does not satisfy it, because it may not be clear which mutational path is taken. For more on different metrics and the triangle inequality, see introduction here: https://dyerlab.github.io/applied_population_genetics/genetic-distances.html

Comment: @MaximilianPress The mutational path lengths may well have been what Nei 1972 was referring to. A metric computed on the nucleotide content alone would not necessarily be comonotonic with such pathlengths.

Comment: @MaximilianPress I wish I could send you the link directly. I can access it through my academic institution. Perhaps you can do the same.

Comment: No longer in academia unfortunately! And my alternative sources don't seem to be working right now.

Comment: I think this is just a way of saying that evolution is not sufficiently deterministic to expect it to follow simple mathematical relationships, and isn't meant to be any more profound than that. I'd think that saying "the purpose of evolution isn't to make neat mathematical results" or "biology doesn't obediently follow the assumptions necessary" would have the same meaning. Or "the triangle inequality doesn't hold here, and that's okay because you shouldn't expect it to". But I don't have access to the original document, either.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your perspective. The concerns about (1) degree of determinism, (2) purpose of evolution, and (3) necessary assumptions are not synonymous. Yet I can see any of them matching Nei's phrasing to an extent. I am sorry to hear that you are also unable to access the original document.

Comment: @DifferentialPleiometry Yes, I don't mean to say they are synonymous, just that I think they are all consistent with the intended meaning. I take it as a bit of a droll statement, in the spirit of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong, and if so I am very sympathetic with the message it communicates.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for reminding me that I want to read [*Science and Statistics*](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Ian.Jermyn/philosophy/writings/Boxonmaths.pdf) by George Box.

Comment: @BryanKrause Having fresh eyes on the paper around the "All models are wrong" quote, I appreciate Box's point of view. I actually didn't know that the paper has a large focus on Fisher's career. I largely agree with Box that when it comes to Statistics, we should be wary of "mathematistry" rather than Math *per se*.